# JavaScript y Lumen

Tags: json, angular, backend

Mi problema viene dado a que cuándo parseo la información del cliente (JavaScript) para que lo reciba el back-end (Lumen) y hago json_decode(variable) me devuelve un null. Pienso que el problema viene dado porque no creo que se pueda hacer lo siguiente:

```
let json = [JSON.stringify(partida),JSON.stringify(personaje),JSON.stringify(caracteristicas),JSON.stringify(habilidades)];
```

**Código que se ejecuta al presionar el botón de mi component.html**

```js
onSubmit() {
    let check = this.habilidades.hEspecializacion.length == 2;
    let check2 = this.habilidades.hProfesion.length == 3;

    this._game.addNewGame(this.partida, this.personaje, this.caracteristicas, this.habilidades).subscribe(
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response['code'] == 200) {

        }
        else {

        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(<any>error);
      }
    )

  }
```

**Servicio que usa la función del componente.ts para añadir una nueva partida**

```js
addNewGame(partida: Partida, personaje: Personaje, caracteristicas: Caracteristicas, habilidades: Habilidades) {
    let json = [JSON.stringify(partida),JSON.stringify(personaje),JSON.stringify(caracteristicas),JSON.stringify(habilidades)];
    console.log(json);
    let params = 'json=' + json;
    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
    let options = { headers: httpHeaders };
    return this._http.post(this.url + '/nuevaPartida', params, { headers: httpHeaders });
  }
```

**Código del back-end de Lumen**

```
public function addGame(Request $request)
{   $inputs = $request->all();
    $decode = json_decode($inputs['json']);
    dd($decode);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te parece bien vamos a desglosarlo un poco, mas o menos es la forma que uso.

Vamos con el servicio.

```
let body= JSON.stringify(partida); // vamos a imaginar que tiene una variable name

    console.log(body);

    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });// en este caso creo que se podría obviar, pero lo dejamos 
httpHeaders .append('Content-Type' , 'application/json');

    return this._http.post(this.url + '/nuevaPartida', body, { headers: httpHeaders });
```

Ahora con Lumen

```
public function addGame(Request $request)
{   $data = json_decode($request->getContents(),true);
     return response()
            ->json(['message' => 'Parece que va bien','data'=>$data['name']);
// **name** por que he comentedo que existia y json para leer la con Angular
    /*dd($data); Esto solo se recoge con cliente tipo postman en angular no se ve correctamente*/
}
```

Espero que te sirva.
Un saludo.

Comment: Me sirvió mucho. Gracias por tu respuesta.